# Sound stops working randomly

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've had several issues with sound stopping randomly and reboot solves the problem but it is annoying especially if it stops in the middle of a video session.

I did a `wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh` from a terminal (based on a post in this forum) to capture information which is posted [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=27086b03a4f8027e120bafbde8975206cc7ca8a1).

If anyone can figure out this output, please tell me what seems to be the problem with sound hardware on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: Seems like it did the trick, I will keep an eye on the issue and post a second confirmation note that sound has not broken down. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
```

`-k` means "kill". The pulseaudio daemon appears to restart as needed, and that seems to wake up the sound for whatever reason.